# same archive template for different custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

Suppose i have registered five custom post type like this

```
america
china
nepal
norway
chile
```

And to template the archive i should use like this inside theme folder isn't it?

```
archive-america.php
archive-china.php
```

and so on?

But the thing is all of them have same code? And i don't want to make five files with same coding ? And basically it violates DRY as welll

Is there any hooks etc. like template redirect etc so that i can use one php file for such selected custom post type like

```
archive-country.php
```

i know i can use `archive.php` but i want to show same teamplate for some selected custom post .

Is it possible?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are [template filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy) for all types of queries. You could use [`archive_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/archive_template) in this case.

```
function wpd210689_template_filter( $archive_template ) {
    $post_types = array( 'america', 'china', 'nepal', 'norway', 'chile' );
    if ( is_post_type_archive ( $post_types ) ) {
        $archive_template = locate_template( 'archive-country.php' );
    }
    return $archive_template;
}
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'wpd210689_template_filter' ) ;
```