# same template for multiple custom post type single

Tags: posts, customization

I know we could use `single-custom-post.php` But i have multiple custom post type
like

```
america
nepal
norway
```

i can do `single-america.php` , `single-nepal.ph`p , `single-norway`. But they almost have same code basically violating `DRY`. I am currently registering such post from plugins . How to show the template for them inside plugin with name lets say `single-country.php`?

I think we can use `template_include` filter? but i still don't have idea to do it?

tried like this

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function ( $template  ) {
    $cpt=["america","nepal","norway"]
    if ( //how to check condition if it is custom post type single ) {
        return ADVANCED_NOTES_DIR . 'country-single.php';
    }
    return $template ;
}) ;
```

So can we use same template for multiple custom post type single?

thank you :)

Comment: This is basically identical to [your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210689/same-archive-template-for-different-custom-post).

Comment: @Milo thanks but i don't think so ? How do i check whether the post is single custom type post or not? thank you. So for that condiition i made this post .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `template_include` or the more specific [`single_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/).

Example code:

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function( $template ) {

  $cpt = [ 'america', 'nepal', 'norway' ];

  return in_array( get_queried_object()->post_type, $cpt, true )
    ? 'path/to/country-single.php'
    : $template;

} );
```

`single_template` filter runs only for singular queries, so you don't need to check you are on a singular view, but just check that the queried post type is one of the CPTs you want to replace the template for.

I used [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) for the scope.